# How to design a table for nodes with 'dynamic' parameters

Tags: database-design

Here is what I am trying to implement:

I have node types which can be created, edited and removed.
Each node type defines some parameters that a node of that type has, along with default parameters that all nodes have.
Each node that is created must have a node type and store the values for the default parameters and the custom parameters dictated by it's node type.

I have already implemented the following but don't know how to continue:

I have a table of node types and a table of parameters where the parameters table has a foreign key to the node type table. (many parameters to 1 node type)

Any help would be great!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fastest way is using a flat structure:

- Figure out your max amount of fields and what types those fields will be
- Create a big wide flat table that has columns like "text1", "text2", "date1", "date..5" etc.
- Have another table that maps those generic column names to whatever your custom nomenclature is based on the type foreign key

Sane people usually use JSON or XML to store dynamic content:

- A lot of RDBMS have good support for parsing XML
- You can create a table with a few of the standard columns like "Type" and "Name" and ahve xml columns for "CustomValues"